# How to see log4J messages in console

Tags: java, configuration, log4j

I have an application in NetBeans where I am trying to use debug messages to log method calls, e.g.:

```
public class PersonService {

     protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PersonService.class.getName());

     public void add(Person person) { 
        logger.debug("PersonService.add called");
        ...
     }
```

My log4j configuration file is in the WEB-INF folder of the project as below:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,console

#Console Appender 
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] [%t %d{hh:mm:ss}] (%F:%M:%L) %m%n
```

I understand that this should print debug messages to the console but so far I get nothing.

I am also receiving this in the output:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is your application finding the configuration file? WEB-INF isn't usually in the classpath. an error message gets written to stdout if the configuration file can't be found, do you see anything like that?

Comment: I think that might be the problem. How do I tell the application where to find the config file? Message details given in question.

Comment: I prefer usingr `Logger.getLogger(PersonService.class)` instead of `Logger.getLogger(PersonService.class.getName())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `log4j.properties` file into `WEB-INF/classes`, you should keep it in classpath.

Another (more correct way) is to keep all your `.properties` file in separate properties folder, which content automatically moved to `WEB-INF/classes` during web archive creation. In Eclipse this kind of folders called *source folders on build path*.

Comment: It's working now. Thanks to zvzdhk and the other respondents. Although I didn't expect so many messages!-)

Comment: Just one thing though: I'm using NetBeans and not Eclipse. But I have Spring.properties in the WEB-INF folder and it is recognised. So why shouldn't log.4j properties be recognised?

Comment: @MrMorgan I guess it depends on concrete library - some attempting to find configuration file in WEB-INF, another - in classpath.

Comment: Maybe I should use Eclipse instead! Thanks.